# December Windows Update disable use of registry keys to set lockscreen image for Windows 11 Professional?

Tags: windows, group-policy, configuration-management

As the title says, to clarify, you can't normally set lockscreen image with GPO for Windows 11 Pro computers, as it only works for Enterprise and Education. However you could set three PersonalizationCSP registry keys and it would work.

I had this setup for one of my customers, but suddenly the 12th December last year, it stopped working.

Does anyone have information regarding this? Do any of you still use PeronalizationCSP registry keys to set lockscreen image with GPO with the latest update and it still works with Pro devices?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

**Important**:

Personalization CSP is supported in Windows Enterprise and Education SKUs. It works in Windows Professional *only when SetEduPolicies in SharedPC CSP is set*, or *when the device is configured in Shared PC mode with BootToCloudPCEnhanced policy*.

---

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/personalization-csp

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/sharedpc-csp

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/clouddesktop-csp#boottocloudpcenhanced